# Отобразить диаграмму тип "Пирог" с нюансами

Tags: javascript, css, диаграммы, highcharts

Необходимо отобразить диаграмму следующего вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал на highcharts, но не нашел информацию как сделать:

1. Проценты внутри сектора. Можно форматировать label, но он уже занят на отображение Хорошо/Плохо и тд.
2. Увеличить размер сектора, можно только его отодвинуть слегка свойством sliced

Если можно сделать похожее на чем то другом, или хитрый кустарный способ - поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно на том же d3.js, а для хитрого кустарного способа нужен Ваш код, чтобы что-то советовать.

Comment: @edem Я пока что ищу как сделать своими руками. Как получится - выложу обязательно

Answer (score 1):

**я знаю что это не решение но как вариант подойдёт, проще для статических диаграмм и отобразить можно любую структуру**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.di {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.di div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.di .left {
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.di .top {
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid blue;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.di .bootom {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #cc0000;
  border-left: 20px solid #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="di">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="bootom"></div>
</div>
```

> http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/ORrLry?editors=110

Comment: Мне очень понравилось =) попробую сделать так